'failed to pull image registry. k8s. io/pause: 3.8' while registry. k8s. io/pause: 3.8 already in my local image list
I was trying " kubectl apply -f nfs-client.yaml "
# nfs-client.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nfs-provisioner
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
       app: nfs-provisioner
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nfs-provisioner
    spec:
      serviceAccount: nfs-provisioner
      containers:
        - name: nfs-provisioner
          image: registry.k8s.io/sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner:v4.0.2
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nfs-client
              mountPath: /persistentvolumes
          env:
            - name: PROVISIONER_NAME
              value: example.com/nfs
            - name: NFS_SERVER
              value: 192.168.176.134
            - name: NFS_PATH
              value: /srv/nfs
      volumes:
        - name: nfs-client
          nfs:
            server: 192.168.176.134
            path: /srv/nfs

When I executed "kubectl get pod", it displayed
$ kubectl get pod
NAME                               READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
nfs-provisioner-7685bb75f5-4lv67   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          15m

then I excuted "kubectl describe pod nfs-provisioner-7685bb75f5-4lv67", it displayed
Name:             nfs-provisioner-7685bb75f5-4lv67
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  nfs-provisioner
Node:             ubuntunode2/192.168.176.136
Start Time:       Sat, 22 Jun 2024 13:53:57 +0000
Labels:           app=nfs-provisioner
                  pod-template-hash=7685bb75f5
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Pending
IP:
IPs:              <none>
Controlled By:    ReplicaSet/nfs-provisioner-7685bb75f5
Containers:
  nfs-provisioner:
    Container ID:
    Image:          registry.k8s.io/sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner:v4.0.2
    Image ID:
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      PROVISIONER_NAME:  example.com/nfs
      NFS_SERVER:        192.168.176.134
      NFS_PATH:          /srv/nfs
    Mounts:
      /persistentvolumes from nfs-client (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-7lmnt (ro)
Conditions:
  Type                        Status
  PodReadyToStartContainers   False
  Initialized                 True
  Ready                       False
  ContainersReady             False
  PodScheduled                True
Volumes:
  nfs-client:
    Type:      NFS (an NFS mount that lasts the lifetime of a pod)
    Server:    192.168.176.134
    Path:      /srv/nfs
    ReadOnly:  false
  kube-api-access-7lmnt:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------                  ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled               18m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/nfs-provisioner-7685bb75f5-4lv67 to ubuntunode2
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  13m (x9 over 18m)     kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to get sandbox image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8": failed to pull image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8": failed to pull and unpack image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8": failed to resolve reference "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8": failed to do request: Head "https://us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/k8s-artifacts-prod/images/pause/manifests/3.8": dial tcp 74.125.23.82:443: connect: connection refused
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  2m51s (x18 over 12m)  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to get sandbox image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8": failed to pull image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8": failed to pull and unpack image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8": failed to resolve reference "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8": failed to do request: Head "https://us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/k8s-artifacts-prod/images/pause/manifests/3.8": dial tcp 64.233.188.82:443: connect: connection refused
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  2m18s                 kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to get sandbox image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8": failed to pull image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8": failed to pull and unpack image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8": failed to resolve reference "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8": failed to do request: Head "https://us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/k8s-artifacts-prod/images/pause/manifests/3.8": dial tcp 64.233.189.82:443: connect: connection refused

Due to the network policy, I pulled images from mirror website and tagged them. I have "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8" and "registry.k8s.io/sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner:v4.0.2" locally (both in master node and worker nodes).
$ sudo ctr images list | grep "registry.k8s.io"
registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8                                                                                   application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json sha256:e0cc6dba04bee00badd8b13495d4411060b5563a9499fbc20e46316328efad30 301.3 KiB linux/amd64 -
registry.k8s.io/sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner:v4.0.2                                          application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json sha256:f741e403b3ca161e784163de3ebde9190905fdbf7dfaa463620ab8f16c0f6423 17.1 MiB  linux/amd64 -
swr.cn-north-4.myhuaweicloud.com/ddn-k8s/registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8                                          application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json sha256:e0cc6dba04bee00badd8b13495d4411060b5563a9499fbc20e46316328efad30 301.3 KiB linux/amd64 -
swr.cn-north-4.myhuaweicloud.com/ddn-k8s/registry.k8s.io/sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner:v4.0.2 application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json sha256:f741e403b3ca161e784163de3ebde9190905fdbf7dfaa463620ab8f16c0f6423 17.1 MiB  linux/amd64 -

So, why is the error "failed to pull image registry. k8s. io/pause: 3.8" still reported with "imagePullPolicy: Never"?

The imagePullPolicy applies to the image defined in the associated image tag not to other images. I suspect (but don't know where) there's a way to configure the system to not (always) pull pause and/or define an alternative location for pause (or assume it's local)

you can check your image is under namespace k8s.io:
ctr -n=k8s.io image list|grep "pause"

if you are using containerd, you can try to specify the sandbox image like this:
version = 2

[plugins]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"]
    sandbox_image = "registry.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.6"

    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".cni]
      bin_dir = "/usr/lib/cni"
      conf_dir = "/etc/cni/net.d"
  [plugins."io.containerd.internal.v1.opt"]
    path = "/var/lib/containerd/opt"

